# Angular2 - Object toString method

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I noticed an interesting application to add toString this object, I wonder if it's a good solution? Is this expected behavior template interpolation?

For example:

```
class Person {
   name: string;
   surname: string;

   toString(): string {
       return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
   }
}
```

When we display this object in template, insted of [object Object] we see toString method result.

```
Username: {{ person }} // Result "Name Surname" insted of "[object Object]"
```

What do you think about it? I know that this is due to the fact that the angular convert object to string, but is it good to use this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `toString()` should be used for debugging purposes only.

For production I would rather use something like

```
class Person {
   name: string;
   surname: string;

   fullName(): string {
       return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
   }
}
```

```
Username: {{ person.fullName }}
```

Comment: Hmmm, Don't you think that those syntax is simpler? In other case I have address object and I'd like to display it in specific format string, so method name toString seems good and I can display it by default.

Comment: What if you want a long form and a short form? Do you then name it `toString()` and `toString2()`? That doesn't make much sense. Rather assing a name that properly reveals the intent of the method from the beginning.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the main purpose of toString is to show the info of the object, not only in debug mode. Imagine you want to show a list of item, where item is Object/Any/Dynamic. You have two option define an interface that has an specific property or use toString(). Languages like python, C#, java in a lot of frameworks use and encourage you to use toString() like default output for tables, grids, etc.
And if you want to use different outputs to short form and long form, you can make a toString aware of it self or you can use inheritance, pipe, etc.

Comment: @titusfx I understand your point of view and I think it's valid to see it this way. I still think it's better to have methods or properties with intention-revealing names and rely on `toString` only for debugging purposes.